# Unable to connect to AWS RDS on my laptop (although my laravel app which is hosted via elastic beanstalk can interact with the RDS)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I created an AWS Elastic Beanstalk env and deployed my laravel app. My laravel app can connect to the database but i cannot connect to the database using any database client on my laptop.

I have already added my **IP address under EC2 -> Security Groups -> Inbound rules** (followed an advice from another stackoverflow post) [Inbound rule entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv8HR.png)

My RDS access is **Publicly accessible under RDS -> Databases -> Connectivity & Security**

I keep getting this [mysql client error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jon0I.png)

What am I missing here? Do I need to change anything else for accessing the RDS remotely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this RDS instance in a private or a public subnet? If it's in a private subnet, it'll not be reachable from outside the VPC. You'll have to create a jump server to connect to it.

You can go through a few checks if RDS is already in the public subnet.

1. make sure SG attached to RDS has an ingress rule on the Mysql port for your IP address.
2. if your IP address is dynamic, make sure it hasn't changed after
   adding the ingress rule to SG.
3. make sure that the public subnet's route table has a route to the internet gateway as well.
4. check instance reachability by running the command `telnet <RDS_hostname> <Port>` on the terminal.

Comment: It is in a public subnet.

Comment: a few checks that you can go through.
1. make sure SG attached to RDS has an ingress rule on the Mysql port for your IP address.
2. if your IP address is dynamic, make sure it hasn't changed after adding the ingress rule to SG.
3. make sure that public subnet's route table has a route to internet gateway as well.
4. check instance reachability by running command `telnet <RDS_hostname> <Port>` on terminal.

Comment: This should have been a comment: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker. Please update your answer by editing the answer instead of answering with the new information in the comments and leaving the old irrelevant answer.